# Why did the villain of Sunshine flicker?

Tags: sunshine

Why did the villain of Danny Boyle's 2007 movie, [Sunshine](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0448134/), flicker?

Also, did he have "superpowers" (he seemed able to either run really fast or phase/teleport)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The villian didn't really 'flicker'. He was just never in focus. It was a effect created by the DOP to give the feeling that he wasn't himself anymore. He was completely engulfed in the cabin fever that he suffered from or the Sun itself.

I don't think he had super powers, but it just seemed like he did because of the circumstances.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunshine_(2007_film)):

> The insane captain of Icarus I, the first ship that was sent to reignite the Sun. Pinbacker was inspired by the character of Sergeant Pinback from Dark Star. The character's disfiguring burns were influenced by the injuries suffered by F1 driver Niki Lauda. Boyle described the character of Pinbacker as a representation of fundamentalism. The director also described the potentially unrealistic presence of Pinbacker as an example of something that breaks the pattern of realism, similar to his scene in Trainspotting (1996) in which Ewan McGregor's character dives into a toilet.

Comment: I did think of this while watching the movie. Unfortunately such visual symbolism doesn't work well imo, as viewers tend to accept what they're shown as real, especially in otherwise rather realistic movies. (Well, even if we understand the symbolism of certain elements, they have to have a working "in world" explanation as well so that they don't break suspension of disbelief.) (Sidenote: Trainspotting was about drugs and hallucinations hence the toilet scene did not really break SoD. The same unrealism breaks a movie like Sunshine... in a bad way, imo.)

Comment: @OpaCitiZen, additionally, a lot of the bad science in Sunshine also breaks it. Like the magical ability for anything on the earth to ever have the power to reignite the sun. They could split half the earth into antimatter and collide the two halves together at the center of the sun and it wouldn't significantly increase its output. - Just finished doing the math, and I believe doing this would cause the sun to explode. Finding [this page on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_%28energy%29) made my math moot. Look near the bottom. (still not enough to increase output)

Comment: If anyone is interested, doing the above to the earth would be the same as the output of the sun for 27,397,260 years. Which puts into perspective how silly these sun bombs were.

Comment: @DampeS8N: Sure. :) But that's part of the story's premise, if you somehow accept that (and a number of other such... minor slips :)), it's okay. Apart from Pinbacker's supernatural presence.

Comment: @OpaCitiZen, I just find it ironic that a failed cinematographic effect damages SoP more than terrible, horrible science. We are talking magical science. In a movie that otherwise tried really hard to look like Hard SF.

Comment: @DampeS8N I get your point and agree with you. :) However, horrible science is less visible to the average (non-scientist) viewer than an absolutely in-our-face effect. (I'm such a viewer in most respects, though even I found a lot of the pseudo-scientific stuff of the movie... questionable, to say the least.)

Comment: I dont think that the effect was failed. I liked what they did and I love that movie. Even if it could never really happen. This is Science Fiction, after all ;P

Comment: With almost all SciFi you have to have a suspension of disbelief on some aspect(s) of the science. For this movie, it was about how the sun works. (It ain't gonna snuff out folks, thre is no need to relight it, and if there were, well it was nice knowing you). manily the physics wasn't bad, once you suspend disbelief on the above.

Comment: @DampeS8N - they did have a theoretical science scenario behind it, the idea wasn't that they were trying to "reignite the sun" by supplying it with energy, rather they were trying to destroy a dangerous form of matter called a Q-ball left over from the Big Bang which was destroying the Sun from the inside. These ideas are explained at http://scienceandfilm.org/articles/separating-the-science-from-the-fiction-in-sunshine/ -- although the article points out that, even granted the existence of Q-balls, even a gigantic nuclear explosion wouldn't really have the energy *density* to destroy them.

Answer (score 3):

Danny Boyle discusses the character and visualisation of Pinbacker at great length in [this interview](http://twitchfilm.com/2007/07/sunshineinterview-with-danny-boyle.html) with TwitchFilm and [this](http://www.blackfilm.com/20070713/features/dannyboyle.shtml) interview with BlackFilm.

My apologies if these two interviews seem very similar (he's clearly memorised his '*talking points*') but both quotes shed light on the different aspects of your questions.

### Why did he flicker?

> *It's not so much what is Pinbacker—obviously he represents
>   fundamentalism—but it's really a challenge to [Capa's] sanity, which
>   is of course what it would be to go out there*
>
> ***Why we visualized him like that is because*** of what I said before about
>   witnessing. It's very difficult to say when somebody has lived out
>   there for that long, it's not possible but who knows what's possible?
>   We've discovered extraordinary things. So **I wanted him to be spectral,
>   but not like a ghost. He's literally like the bits that make him
>   up—the protons and neutrons that make us all up—have kind of
>   reorganized in some way.**

### Did he have superpowers?

> **Q :** *Why did you add in the radiation-scarred insane mad-killer
>   Pinbacker character?*
>
> **DB:** *It's introducing him into an otherwise realistically based film.
>   Otherwise, it's an extreme psychological element, really. In a way,
>   he's a character. He's based on the guy who piloted the first ship,
>   who has had this transformation....*
>
> *You have to represent that in some way, and we represented that with
>   Pinbacker, this guardian of the gates of heaven or hell, whatever you
>   want to call it. He stands there as a guardian at the gateway. I
>   wanted to depict him in a way that was as extreme as I could do, which
>   I could do technically, which is this blurring, this stretching. You
>   take that kind of risk with somebody. **I wanted him to feel that,
>   literally, the protons and neutrons that make him up had been
>   reorganized somehow--that he was no longer recognizable as a human**,
>   except that he is still speaking with a human voice and he is captain
>   of the first ship.*

Answer (score -3):

People I have two separate science fictional answers here:  I feel that if the technology was present to convert dark matter or maybe its zero point energy which one of these is what most the universe is made of to photonic energy that would create the mass and Nuclear fusion to create a star.   I think that is what the bomb in Sunshine suggested.  That would be smashing two dark matter particles together to stir a chain reaction by what means was left to the audience to decide.   Second answer for Pimbacker or however you spell his name,  the movie suggested to me that the reason for the blurryness with him had to do with getting so close to the sun for so long that his body and space time became distorted due to the intense gravity of the sun.  This is the answer I get from a sci fi perspective.  After all this was science fiction as in warped science.   Thanks  for listening.